# Replace string at the starting position of fields

Tags: t-sql

I would like to update my table and replace string `CarHer` into `MobileAuto` in varchar field but only the if it's at the starting position in entire value stirng. For instance i got this input:

```
CarHer machine sixt CarHer emerte67 34
CarHer
CarHer right 22CarHer
CarHer 222 ass
```

So at the end i would like to achieve this:

```
MobileAuto machine sixt CarHer emerte67 34
MobileAuto
MobileAuto right 22CarHer
MobileAuto 222 ass
```

How can i do this in very safety way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is STUFF()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([SomeCol] varchar(50))  Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('CarHer machine sixt CarHer emerte67 34')
,('CarHer')
,('CarHer right 22CarHer')
,('CarHer 222 ass')
 
Update @YourTable
 Set SomeCol = stuff(SomeCol,1,6,'MobileAuto') 
Where SomeCol like 'CarHer%'

Select * From @YourTable
```

**Updated Table**

```
SomeCol
MobileAuto machine sixt CarHer emerte67 34
MobileAuto
MobileAuto right 22CarHer
MobileAuto 222 ass
```

**EDIT: As a Select**

```
SELECT SomeCol
     , NewVal = stuff(SomeCol,1,6,'MobileAuto') 
 From YourTable
Where SomeCol like 'CarHer%'
```

Comment: you very sure this is safe? I thought some replace function or whatsoever

Comment: @Arie Based on your sample data ... yes.  However, if you have concerns, you can verify with a SELECT SomeCol, NewVal = stuff(SomeCol,1,6,'MobileAuto')  From YourTable

Comment: @Arie See EDIT: As a Select